# Using nslookup with google IPv6 DNS?

Tags: nslookup

I am trying to use nslookup to query google.com with 2001:4860:4860::8888, which is google IPv6 DNS. But I get no response, eg connection. always times out.

When I try same procedure just as DNS put 8.8.8.8, which is IPv4 DNS, everything works fine.

What I am missing here?

PS. I am using mac

EDIT:

```
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
```

gives output

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.212.46
```

but

```
nslookup google.com 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

gives output

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Could you please paste the output for both runs - IPv4 as well as IPv6 ?

Comment: `nslookup -q=AAAA google.com` *I am using mac* `host -t AAAA google.com`

Comment: Silly question, but... does your ISP give you public IPv6 or you have only local v6 addresses (fe80:...)?

Comment: @Akina: That's for looking up IPv6 data, not for sending queries _over_ IPv6.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: `nslookup google.com -2001:4860:4860::8844` ? `nslookup /server 2001:4860:4860::8844 google.com` ?

Comment: I am trying to lookup hostname IP, using provided DNS

Comment: Take a look at here, please: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/dns64  I don't know OSX, try to find "Some NAT64 implementations are known not to work with Google Public DNS64:" - does it help?

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful in understanding networks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve this. It was due to lack of understanding how IPv4 and IPv6 networks function.

I was connected to IPv4 wifi. Trying to nslookup with 8.8.8.8 would obviously work. But trying to access IPv6 DNS from IPv4 network does not work.

If I switch to IPv6 wifi, nslookup with 2001:4860:4860::8844 DNS will yield correct results. Also if I try nslookup with 8.8.8.8 it will also work, since I can access IPv4 DNS from IPv6 network.